# Probit with Likert Scale independent variables

Tags: regression, categorical-data, binary-data, likert, probit

I am doing some research on effectiveness. I have data from a questionnaire with likert scale answers and a dependent variable which is a dummy variable. I have done some research before with nominal data and just used a probit regression analysis on the data with the dummy variable as dependent variable.

I was wondering if I can use the probit on this data too.

Comment: Welcome to our site! There's no need to sign your posts - your username and a link to your userpage automatically appears at the bottom right of any post you make.

Answer (score 2):

You can use binary choice models such as logit, exact logit and probit regression in the following cases

**Independent variable**

- Dummy variables (= binary variables)
- ordinal data (e.g. likert scale)
- nominal data
- censored data
- truncated data
- several other types of data

**Dependent variable**

- Only binary variables

To answer your question in one phrase: **Yes, it is possible.**